# Chamar script python através de um script php acessado pelo browser

Tags: php, python, linux

Eu tenho um script php que irá receber upload de videos e eu gostaria de converter estes videos utilizando o ffmpeg.

Criei um script python que recebe parametros do php e chama o ffmpeg para fazer a conversão.

index.php

```
<?php

$data = array('filePath' => 'video.mov');

$result = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python /home/fernando/Workspace/lab1/public_html/converter.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
```

converter.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys, json, subprocess, string, random

class Converter():

WORK_DIR = '/home/fernando/Workspace/lab1/public_html'
DESTINATION_DIR = '/home/fernando/Workspace/lab1/public_html/videos/'
NEW_AUDIO = 'audio.mp3'

def __init__(self, data):
    try:
        os.chdir(self.WORK_DIR)
        self.arg = data
    except:
        print "ERROR"
        sys.exit(1)     


def generateId():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase ) for _ in range(12))      


def convertVideo(self, type):

    convertedFileName = self.DESTINATION_DIR + self.generateId() + '.' + type

    typesDic = {
                'mp4': ['/usr/bin/ffmpeg', '-loglevel', 'quiet', '-i', self.arg['filePath'], '-i', self.NEW_AUDIO, '-map', '0:0', '-map', '1', '-shortest', '-codec', 'copy', convertedFileName, '-y'], 
                'ogv': ['/usr/bin/ffmpeg', '-loglevel', 'quiet', '-i', self.arg['filePath'], '-i', self.NEW_AUDIO, '-map', '0:0', '-map', '1', '-shortest', '-vcodec', 'libtheora', '-acodec', 'libvorbis',  convertedFileName, '-y'] 
               }

    sp = subprocess.Popen(typesDic[type], shell=True)

    out, err = sp.communicate()

    if err:
        return {'status': 'error'}

    return {'status': 'success', 'filename': convertedFileName}




data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])

c = Converter(data)
print c.convertVideo('mp4')
print c.convertVideo('ogv')
```

Estes códigos estão funcionando da maneira que eu preciso, mas apenas se eu chama-los
 **via linha de comando**.

Ex: `$ php index.php` 
ou: `$ ./converter.py '{"fileName": "video.avi"}'`

Se eu acessar via browser, que era a minha principal intenção, não funciona.

O que será que está errado? 
É possível fazer isso via browser?
Teria uma melhor abordagem?

Editado:

Saida do log do apache:

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg' ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers built on Apr 26 2014 18:52:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:1.2.6-1~trusty1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static libavutil 52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100 libavcodec 54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100 libavformat 54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104 libavdevice 53. 5.103 / 53. 5.103 libavfilter 3. 42.103 / 3. 42.103 libswscale 2. 2.100 / 2. 2.100 libswresample 0. 17.102 / 0. 17.102 libpostproc 52. 2.100 / 52. 2.100 Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}

Comment: Você sabe por que não funciona? Olhou os logs, ou algo do tipo? Minha suspeita é que embora seu usuário comum tenha acesso a esse arquivo, o usuário do Apache (ou de seja lá qual *webserver* você está usando) talvez não tenha. Outra possibilidade é que o PHP esteja executando em [`safe_mode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.safe-mode.php) no *webserver*, mas não quando você invoca via linha de comando. Verifique os logs de erro, deve ter alguma informação adicional que ajude a explicar o problema.

Comment: Olhei nos logs. Tá imprimindo a mesma mensagem que o ffmpeg imprime quando é invocado sem nenhum parâmetro. Editei a pergunta adicionando a saida do log

Comment: Como fica a string final mandada pro shell? Já tentou copiar a string que o script python executa direto no shell do S.O.? Parece que a saída do log do apache indica que o ffmpeg não entendeu os argumentos passados.

Comment: A chamada do Python pelo PHP [parece correta](https://ideone.com/s2xWUW). O script Python também, e embora ele dependa mais do que eu gostaria da pasta corrente (primeiro você chama `os.chdir`, depois chama `Popen` sem especificar um `cwd`) ele *ainda* parece correto... Eu sugiro logo antes de chamar o ffmpeg imprimir duas coisas na saída/log: 1) a pasta corrente (`os.getcwd()`) e 2) o comando a ser passado pro `Popen`. A propósito, a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) recomenda que ao chamar `Popen` com `shell=True` se passe os args como string.

Comment: Legal @mgibsonbr, obrigado pelas dicas. Retirei o parametro shell=True, que a documentação também diz que pode abrir brechas de segurança. Vou eliminar o chdir trabalhando sempre com caminhos absolutos.

Comment: @Thomas, fiz um print no script python do comando que ele está executando e rodei manualmente direto no shell. Está correto.

Comment: @LuísFernandodeAlmeida Como você já tem um caminho absoluto à mão, é só juntar com seu arquivo - `os.path.join(WORK_DIR, self.arg['filePath'])`. Só não sei se vai resolver, pois apesar de tudo seu código ainda parece correto... E você chegou a olhar se o usuário do Apache tem permissão de acessar seu arquivo?

Comment: Finalmente... eram realmente as permissões. Embora os diretórios destino e os scripts estivessem com as permissões corretas, o ffmpeg não tinha permissão para ler os arquivos de input do video e do audio. Agora funcionou! Coloquei no meu server de testes (http://codefield.ml/) Sucessso! Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Meu problema foi resolvido, sou novo por aqui e gostaria de saber se preciso responder a minha própria pergunta ou posso deixar assim como está, somente com os comentários.

Comment: Responda, pode ser que ajude mais pessoas no futuro.

Comment: Tentou imprimir na web o resultado e rodar diretamente no shell para ver o retorno de '/usr/bin/python /home/fernando/Workspace/lab1/public_html/converter.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data));

Comment: As vezes está tudo ok, pode ser algum problema no escapeshellarg(json_encode($data))!!!

Comment: Finalmente resolvido. Eram realmente as permissões. Embora os diretórios destino dos arquivos e os scripts estivessem com as permissões corretas, o ffmpeg não tinha permissão para ler os arquivos de input do video e do audio. Depois de alteradas as permissões dos arquivos de entrada para o ffmpeg, funcionou tranquilamente. Obrigado a todos pelas dicas.